# Convert XmlDocument to String

Tags: c#, string, escaping, quotes, xmldocument

Here is how I'm currently converting **XMLDocument** to **String**

```
StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
XmlTextWriter xmlTextWriter = new XmlTextWriter(stringWriter);

xmlDoc.WriteTo(xmlTextWriter);

return stringWriter.ToString();
```

The problem with this method is that if I have **"** ((quotes) which I have in attributes) it escapes them.

For Instance:

```
<Campaign name="ABC">
</Campaign>
```

Above is the expected XML. But it returns

```
<Campaign name=\"ABC\">
</Campaign>
```

I can do **String.Replace "\"** but is that method okay? Are there any side-effects? Will it work fine if the XML itself contains a **"\"**

Answer (score 210, accepted):

There aren't any quotes. It's just VS debugger. Try printing to the console or saving to a file and you'll see. As a side note: always dispose disposable objects:

```
using (var stringWriter = new StringWriter())
using (var xmlTextWriter = XmlWriter.Create(stringWriter))
{
    xmlDoc.WriteTo(xmlTextWriter);
    xmlTextWriter.Flush();
    return stringWriter.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
}
```

Comment: +1 for fixing the code to use `using` blocks and not `XmlTextWriter`.

Comment: Worthing noting (as mentioned in the remarks here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlwriter.aspx) that the elements and attributes will not be written until you call the Close method of the XmlWriter.

Comment: Some of them may be written immediately.  It depends on buffering.  Regardless, I added a call to `Flush`, though a call to `Close` or just closing the `xmlTextWriter` `using` block would accomplish the same.

Comment: To make the xml pretty, pass in this settings object to XmlWriter.Create: XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
                    settings.Indent = true;
                    settings.IndentChars = "    ";
                    settings.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;

Answer (score 737):

Assuming xmlDoc is an XmlDocument object whats wrong with xmlDoc.OuterXml?

```
return xmlDoc.OuterXml;
```

The [OuterXml property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnode.outerxml.aspx) returns a string version of the xml.

Comment: Well you are right. I tried that first but when I saw the quotes in the debugger. I thought its because of OuterXml and try that StringWriter method. But I was wrong the quotes were only in the debugger. So I'll just use OuterXml. Thanks

Comment: Worked for me! Just do a null check on xmlDoc!
return xmlDoc == null ? "xmlDoc is null" : xmlDoc.OuterXml;

Comment: @SarjanWebDev if you think your object could be null, then the null-check goes without saying and for every answer here; and really for every interaction with an object in C# - personally I try to ensure objects are always constructed so that I don't have to bloat the code with null-checks everywhere... i guess it just depends on your code base...

Comment: (y) but OuterXml doesn't include declarative tag <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>

Comment: @hazjack I wouldn't expect it to, that doesn't make sense; in any event w3 says it optional for v1 spec http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#sec-prolog-dtd

Comment: @hazjack also I would say that the encoding format doesn't really apply to the c# string more so the final output if you were to write to file or stream.

Comment: Yes, thanks for the link. The version 1.1 says it must have an xml declaration http://www.w3.org/TR/xml11/#sec-prolog-dtd

Comment: @hazjack ok I see... your example was for v1.0

Comment: @hazjack if you want declarative tag then make use of the XmlDeclaration Class https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldeclaration.aspx - if you then want to write it to file then then use the save method found on you XmlDocument instance https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dw229a22.aspx - to me the declarative tag only makes sense if you're writing to say file and not a C# string

Comment: Should be the accepted answer since you can't use XmlWriter in some platforms like UWP

Comment: Large files throw OUtOfMemoryException

Answer (score 13):

If you are using `Windows.Data.Xml.Dom.XmlDocument` version of `XmlDocument` (used in UWP apps for example), you can use `yourXmlDocument.GetXml()` to get the XML as a string.

Answer (score 7):

As an extension method:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static string AsString(this XmlDocument xmlDoc)
    {
        using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
        {
            using (XmlTextWriter tx = new XmlTextWriter(sw))
            {
                xmlDoc.WriteTo(tx);
                string strXmlText = sw.ToString();
                return strXmlText;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now to use simply:

```
yourXmlDoc.AsString()
```

Answer (score 3):

you can use `xmlDoc.InnerXml` property to get xml in string

Answer (score 2):

`"` is shown as `\"` in the debugger, but the data is correct in the string, and you don't need to replace anything.  Try to dump your string to a file and you will note that the string is correct.