# Converting XML to string using C#

Tags: c#, xml

I have a function as below

```
public string GetXMLAsString(XmlDocument myxml)
    {
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.LoadXml(myxml);
       
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        XmlTextWriter tx = new XmlTextWriter(sw);
        doc.WriteTo(tx);

        string str = sw.ToString();// 
        return str;
    }
```

I'm passing an XML to this method from an another method. But in the `doc.loadxml()`, the system is expecting a string and since I'm passing an XML, it throws error.

How to solve this issue?

Comment: duplicate:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2407302/convert-xmldocument-to-string

Comment: Voting to close this, as it should have been in the first place, OP had simply confused how to use the typed parameter that was already passed in.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

[As Chris suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6161159/converting-xml-to-string-using-c-sharp/13026108#13026108), you can do it like this:

```
public string GetXMLAsString(XmlDocument myxml)
{
    return myxml.OuterXml;
}
```

Or like this:

```
public string GetXMLAsString(XmlDocument myxml)
    {

        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        XmlTextWriter tx = new XmlTextWriter(sw);
        myxml.WriteTo(tx);

        string str = sw.ToString();// 
        return str;
    }
```

and if you really want to create a new `XmlDocument` then do this

```
XmlDocument newxmlDoc= myxml
```

Comment: 1 st answer Works Perfectly

Answer (score 31):

There's a much simpler way to convert your XmlDocument to a string; use the **OuterXml** property. The [OuterXml property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnode.outerxml.aspx) returns a string version of the xml.

```
public string GetXMLAsString(XmlDocument myxml)
{
    return myxml.OuterXml;
}
```

Comment: For future readers, in this case there is no need to use a method to expose this functionality at all.

Comment: @ChrisSchaller I find this comment a little cryptic - what do you mean; has `OuterXml` been replaced with something else?

Comment: I mean what is the point of wrapping this call in the `GetXMLAsString()` method at all, just tell OP to use `XmlDocument.OuterXml`.  I know this was answered a long time ago, I'm coming across noob developers referencing this answer as the reason they created a `GetXMLAsString()` method and I keep rejecting their commits ;)

Comment: @ChrisSchaller lol oh I see, yes the answer satisfied the original OP's method in the question - perhaps there was a interface or a need for abstraction for unit tests etc. Anyway I'm amazed this one, with the same answer had so many upvotes and still receives them https://stackoverflow.com/a/2407324/81053

Answer (score 4):

```
   public string GetXMLAsString(XmlDocument myxml)
    {
        using (var stringWriter = new StringWriter())
        {
            using (var xmlTextWriter = XmlWriter.Create(stringWriter))
            {
               myxml.WriteTo(xmlTextWriter);
               return stringWriter.ToString();
            }

        }    
}
```

Comment: +1 for `using`, the detour with `GetStringBuilder()` isn't necessary, `stringWriter.ToString()` will do it

Answer (score -1):

String pathFile = "C:\File.XML";
String readConfiguration = File.ReadAllText(pathFile , Encoding.Unicode);

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**