# Converting an XML file to string type

Tags: c#, xml

How can we write an XML file into a string variable?
Here is the code I have,the variable content is supposed to return an XML string:

```
    public string GetValues2()
    {
        string content = "";
        XmlTextWriter textWriter = new XmlTextWriter(content, null);
        textWriter.WriteStartElement("Student");
        textWriter.WriteStartElement("r", "RECORD", "urn:record");
        textWriter.WriteStartElement("Name", "");
        textWriter.WriteString("Student");
        textWriter.WriteEndElement();
        textWriter.Close();

        return contents;

    }
```

Comment: When I try this the program says that I need to define a path instead of content

Comment: do you want to read xml file into string. am I correct?

Comment: If you want create `xml` file and then assign it to `string` `variable` use Linq 2 Xml it's the fastest way.

Comment: @Sachin:No,I want to generate an XML file  and save it into a string variable,I must not save any files or use any files from the hard disk,I appreciate your help

Comment: @harry180:thanks,but how can I do that?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Something like this

```
string xmlString =  System.IO.File.ReadAllText(fileName);
```

Here is good answer to create `XmlDocument`
[XDocument or XMLDocument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1542073/xdocument-or-xmldocument)

Comment: Be aware that File.ReadAllText will lock the file. If you do not wish to lock the file you should use a FileStream with a StreamReader (in a using statement). (var fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite)). The same remark if you use XmlDocument.Load() this will also lock the file. To avoid use the stream alternative.

Answer (score 4):

You can try:

```
static string GetXmlString(string strFile)
{
    // Load the xml file into XmlDocument object.
    XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
    try
    {
        xmlDoc.Load(strFile);
    }
    catch (XmlException e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
    }
    // Now create StringWriter object to get data from xml document.
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    XmlTextWriter xw = new XmlTextWriter(sw);
    xmlDoc.WriteTo(xw);
    return sw.ToString();
}
```

or just use XmlDocument.InnerXml property to get XML string.

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load("path to your file");
string xmlcontents = doc.InnerXml;
```

Answer (score 2):

HI Pedram You can Try the below code

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();

doc.LoadXml("yourXMLPath");
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
XmlTextWriter tx = new XmlTextWriter(sw);
doc.WriteTo(tx);
sw.ToString();
```

Comment: Thanks but I want to generate an XML file and save into the a string variable,I must not load or save files into or from hard disk

Answer (score 2):

Try this-

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(your text string);

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
foreach (XmlNode node in doc.DocumentElement.ChildNodes)
{
    sb.Append(char.ToUpper(node.Name[0]));
    sb.Append(node.Name.Substring(1));
    sb.Append(' ');
    sb.AppendLine(node.InnerText);
}
return sb;
```

have a look on this too-

```
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    XmlTextWriter tx = new XmlTextWriter(sw);
    myxml.WriteTo(tx);

    string str = sw.ToString();// 
    return str;
```

and if you really want to create a new XmlDocument then do this

```
XmlDocument newxmlDoc= myxml
```

Comment: This is **literally a direct copy** of the answer posted by @Kimtho6, here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6161182/12068778