# Edit item in a dynamically created list of objects

Tags: c#, winforms, linq, lambda

I have a C# winforms application. In this application I am creating a list of `CanMessage` objects dynamically from an xml file.

The xml file is constructed as below

```
<message id="0x641" ecu="BCM" name="BODY9" dlc="8" cyclicrate="500">
<bytes>
  <byte0>0x0</byte0>
  <byte1>0x0</byte1>
  <byte2>0x0</byte2>
  <byte3>0x0</byte3>
  <byte4>0x0</byte4>
  <byte5>0x0</byte5>
  <byte6>0x0</byte6>
  <byte7>0x0</byte7>
</bytes>
```

The `Canmessage` object is constructed like this:

```
CanMessage(String name,String _EcuName, ulong id, ushort dlc,int[] bytearray , int cyclic)
    {

        this.Name = name;
        this.EcuName = _EcuName;
        this.Id = id;
        this.Dlc = dlc;
        this.Bytes = new int[dlc];
        this.CyclicRate = cyclic;
        int i = 0;
        for(i = 0; i < dlc; i++)
        {
            this.Bytes[i] = bytearray[i];
        }
    }
```

Below is how I am building my `Canmessage` list:

```
public void BuildCanList()
    {
        try
        {
            XmlDocument xd = new XmlDocument();
            xd.Load(XmlFile);

            XmlNodeList nodelist = xd.SelectNodes("/messages/message");

            foreach (XmlNode n in nodelist)
            {
                String name, ecuname;
                ulong id;
                ushort dlc;
                int[] bytes = new int[Convert.ToInt32(n.Attributes.GetNamedItem("dlc").Value)];
                int cyclic;

                name = n.Attributes.GetNamedItem("name").Value.ToString();
                id = (ulong)Convert.ToInt32(n.Attributes.GetNamedItem("id").Value, 16);
                ecuname = n.Attributes.GetNamedItem("ecu").Value.ToString();
                dlc = (ushort)Convert.ToByte(n.Attributes.GetNamedItem("dlc").Value);
                cyclic = Convert.ToInt32(n.Attributes.GetNamedItem("cyclicrate").Value);
                XmlNode sn = n.SelectSingleNode("bytes");
                for (ushort i = 0; i < dlc; i++)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        bytes[i] = Convert.ToInt32(sn.ChildNodes.Item(i).InnerText, 16);
                    }
                    catch(Exception e)
                    {
                        bytes[i] = 0x0;
                        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Error Building can Message: {0}", e.ToString()));
                    }

                }
                CanMessage cm = new CanMessage(name, ecuname, id, dlc, bytes, cyclic);
                CanList.Add(cm);
            }
```

My list is being created with no issues. My question is after my list has been created I will sometimes need to do some bit manipulation on certain bytes of a certain `Canmessage`. How can I select a message from the list based on its `name` property and then edit certain bytes from that message? I know how to select a message from the list using lambda expression and linq. But I don't know how to then combine that select method with an edit and save method or if this is even the best way to go about doing this.

Comment: What do you mean? Note that you could use a dictionary in order to go directly to your object with a name (key-value pair). From there you would get the value and then you could edit it as usual without a `linq` expression.

Comment: In case you don't know, you can also use a Lookup and have 1 key with multiple values (in case you have 1 name appearing multiple time)

Comment: Reading from xml into object is **deserialization**. Then you can edit the list as any list. Saving would be **serialization**. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42708070/how-do-i-create-a-dto-in-c-sharp-asp-net-from-a-fairly-complex-json-response) for serialization and deserialization and editing will be simply the same as editing any list or object.

Comment: 1) deserialize 2) edit in memory 3) serialize. Or edit XML file directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand your problem statement correctly, you need to find a specific `CanMessage` in the `List<CanMessage>` and edit its properties to your liking. Since your `CanMessage` is an object, it's being accessed by reference and therefore your edits will get reflected everywhere you reference it from.

Consider the following:

```cs
{
    var CanList = new List<CanMessage>(); // I am assuming this is what it is
    BuildCanList(CanList);

    var messagetoEdit = CanList.First(m => m.Name == "BODY9");
    messagetoEdit.Bytes[1]= 0xff;
    messagetoEdit.Bytes[2]= 0xff;
    messagetoEdit.Bytes[3]= 0xff;
    messagetoEdit.Bytes[4]= 0xff;

    var newMessagetoEdit = CanList.First(m => m.Name == "BODY9"); // you will see that values have changed here

    //in case you wanted to serialise the list back, heres a snippet on how you could do it, for more details see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6161159/converting-xml-to-string-using-c-sharp
    //this is just to prove a point that changing bytes has effect, 
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();   
    var serialiser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<CanMessage>));
    serialiser.Serialize(sw, CanList);
    sw.ToString();
}
```

I hope this clarifies

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Thank you for the explanation it clears things up for me.