# how to pass xml document as a string to a asp.net webservice

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hi i have the xml document in my asp.net web application . I want to assign the xml document to a string and pass that string to a asp.net webservice. Can anyone able to help me to do this ?
Thank you

Comment: Possible answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2407302/convert-xmldocument-to-string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
xml.Load("file1.xml");
string xmlString = xml.OuterXml;
```

and you can pass the xmlString.

Answer (score 1):

May be you need this:

```
        XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
        StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
        XmlTextWriter textWriter = new XmlTextWriter(stringWriter);
        xmlDoc.WriteTo(textWriter);
        string xmlText = stringWriter.ToString();
```