# Output XmlDocument as XML

Tags: vb.net

I have a function which reads a string to an XMLDocument.

I wish to then output the XML in that document to the screen.

```
Dim L As String = P.ToString()
Dim xmlDoc As XmlDocument = New XmlDocument()
xmlDoc.LoadXml(L)
Context.Response.Write(xmlDoc)
```

the above does not work, I have also tried using

```
Return(xmlDoc)
```

with no success. How should I perform this function? Should I not be using XMLDocument?

Comment: I don't get it.  `L` is already the XML document as a string, right?  So, if all you want is that, just return `L`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the possible ways is to use a StringWriter:

```
Using stringWriter = New StringWriter()
    Using xmlTextWriter = XmlWriter.Create(stringWriter)
        xmlDoc.WriteTo(xmlTextWriter)
        xmlTextWriter.Flush()
        result = stringWriter.GetStringBuilder().ToString()
    End Using
End Using
```

On the example above, your XML will be stored into the **result** variable.

The C# equivalent code may be found on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2407302/convert-xmldocument-to-string).

Answer (score 0):

```
        StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
        XmlTextWriter xmlTextWriter = new XmlTextWriter(stringWriter);

        document.WriteTo(xmlTextWriter);

        Console.WriteLine(stringWriter.ToString());
        Console.Read();
```

Comment: sorry have entered the answer as c#.net but it should be able to converted to vb.net